# Problems with cv::Rectangle in C++

Tags: c#, c++, opencv

I have a problem when drawing a rectangle in a cv :: mat. I am making a communication between Unity and C ++ to generate an Android application.

I use the webcamtexture camera of unity and I send the information of to C ++ using the PInvoke method. Once in the C ++ code, I want to draw a rectangle but I get more than one in the image (see image) and I really do not understand why. I hope you can help me I attach the C++ and C# code.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

C#

```
void Update()
{
    //texto.text = texto.text + " / "+ testo().ToString();
    imgData = null;
    imgData = new byte[width * height * 3];
    resultado = null;
    resultado = new byte[width * height * 3];
    color = webcam.GetPixels32();
    int bytesPerPixel = 3;
    const int indexR = 0;
    const int indexG = 1;
    const int indexB = 2;
    for (var i = 0; i < color.Length; i++)
    {
        imgData[(i * bytesPerPixel) + indexR] = color[i].r;
        imgData[(i * bytesPerPixel) + indexG] = color[i].g;
        imgData[(i * bytesPerPixel) + indexB] = color[i].b;
    }
    color = null;
    ProcessFrame(imgData, resultado, 0, 0, 0,0, nuevo);
    nuevo = false;
    textura2 = new Texture2D(width, height, TextureFormat.RGB24, false);
    textura2.LoadRawTextureData(resultado);
    textura2.Apply();
    renderer.material.mainTexture = textura2;
    textura2 = null;
    Resources.UnloadUnusedAssets();
}
```

C++

```
void ProcessFrame(unsigned char* arr, unsigned char* resu,int posx, int posy, int poswidth, int posheight,bool nuevo) {
    Mat dst;//dst image
    trueRect.x = 150;
    trueRect.y = 150;
    trueRect.width = 100;
    trueRect.height = 100;
    wi = poswidth;
    he = posheight;
    mal = 20;
    dst = Mat(tamWid,tamHeid,CV_8UC3, arr);
    rectangle(dst, Point(50,50), Point(100,100), cv::Scalar(0, 255, 255));
    copy(dst.datastart, dst.dataend, resu);
}
```

Comment: I cannot say it for sure, but my guess is that you have shifted columns with rows, that is OpenCV stores image data columnwise and Unity (OpenGL) rowwise (or other way around). Can you debug this C++ code and check the matrix with ImageWatch plugin? Or simply save dst with `cv::imwrite`. Also, you should first make copy of dst and later draw on it. As for now you change the original image and copy it, so both will have rectangle.

Comment: Sorry but i´m not sure what are you telling me. I passed the information of the size of the image in a previous function, it worked with a resolution of 640x480. I do not understand exactly what you want to say with edge, and much less how you could solve it. 

About Debug, I can´t use, because i´m using shared libraries in unity to create an Android application.

Comment: @R2RT opencv is row major. The problem is `dst = Mat(tamWid,tamHeid,CV_8UC3, arr);` it is rows, columns, in the constructor, so it should be `dst = Mat(tamHeid,tamWid,CV_8UC3, arr);` then you have to also check if the data is column wise or row wise, if it is column wise you need to leave it as before and transpose the mat

Comment: @api55 Ye, I think you are right. You should make it an answer. Urko, try with `Mat(tamHeid,tamWid,CV_8UC3, arr);`

Comment: BTW, you do not have several rectangles, it is only one, just that it paints as if the width is longer. The coordinates seems to be weird as well, since in OpenCV the (0,0) is on the top left corner. a rectangle with points 50, 50  and 100 100, should be high and not low. I think you have to recheck and have the dataArray properly restrucutred before painting. Actually i checked the [docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Texture2D.GetPixels32.html) and you have them bottom to top, left to right

Comment: Final comment, ´int bytesPerPixel = 3;´ should be 4... it is from a 32bit colorspace... weird that you do not get weird colors if this is shifted....

Comment: it works, thanks you every body

Solution: Mat(tamHeid,tamWid,CV_8UC3, arr);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just for the sake of completeness I will post the answer.

The problem is in the line

```
dst = Mat(tamWid,tamHeid,CV_8UC3, arr);
```

The [constructor of Mat](https://docs.opencv.org/trunk/d3/d63/classcv_1_1Mat.html#a3620c370690b5ca4d40c767be6fb4ceb) takes as first two arguments rows and then columns, in your case is columns and rows.

So it should be:

```
dst = Mat(tamHeid,tamWid,CV_8UC3, arr);
```

## Other considerations

As I said in the comments, you should be aware of certain possible source of errors, since the conventions are not the same in OpenCV and Unity. One of them is the origin of your 2D coordinate system. In OpenCV is on the top left and in Unity, or at least with the `GetPixels32` function is in the bottom left of the image.

Another possible problem is the Colorspace. OpenCV when it loads, saves, and other functions expects BGR images, while in other frameworks they use RGB or RGBA which is 32 bits.